# GWT Celltable reset

Tags: gwt

I'm creating an application with GWT. The application has a search tool, which would give the list to be added to the celltable. for the first time, when the celltable is loaded with the list, it shows the loading animator. However, for the alternative loads, its not being shown up. Is there anyway I could make this animator to be shown???

For instance, consider I'm populating the celltable based on a buttonclickevent. Now, when I click the button for the first time, the animator is shown. on successful completion of the search, the table would be populated with the list. Things are fine until this.

I want to search with some other parameter and click the button. Now, I want the existing table elements to be reset. i.e. to remove the elements from the table and want the table to display the animator (loading...) to be displayed on the celltable.

I have tried to set the rowcount to zero, which solved the first condition. However, I need the animator to be displayed. Is there any solution?? Is this possible at all??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `updateRowCount(0, false)` then the loading widget will be displayed.  With `updateRowCount(0, true)` it won't be displayed.

It took me like 25 minutes to figure this out - it makes sense in retrospect.